# No module called spectrogram

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, spectrogram

Hi I am having a little trouble with the module `spectrogram` which I need to use in order to create spectrograms from my wav files.

I repeatedly get the error message `No module named spectrogram` when importing on my Windows which is running Python version 2.7.12. In contrast when importing the module on my mac which runs version 2.7.11 I have no problems. I can't find anything that suggests that this is a version specific problem and was hoping someone might be able to help me fix this.

Here is the code I am using to import the needed modules. This runs absolutely fine on my mac, but won't run on Windows.

```
    import glob
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.io import wavfile
    import spectrogram as sp
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Have you tried to import using its full path, something like `import scipy.signal.spectrogram` if that is the thing you mentioned?

Comment: Or can you give a link to the `spectrogram` you refer to? I didn't find a `spectrogram` model.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried importing using the whole path, it comes up with the same error message. I don't have a link to the spectrogram, its from code I have been given by someone else which runs fine on my mac

Answer (score 0):

Spectrogram is a part of scipy, you must make that known.

```
from scipy import signal
signal.spectrogram(bla,bla,bla)
```

Comment: Comsider adding a description for your code so that users that visit this post in the future can understand it.